# Mutipart File upload using Angularjs and Spring

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, jboss, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload files using Angularjs for REST API exposed via Spring :

This is my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = util/images/{partyId},
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
public JsonNode uploadPartyRefImage(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile inputFile,
                                    @PathVariable String partyId){
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jNode = null;
    try {
        String[] fileInput = ((DiskFileItem) ((CommonsMultipartFile) inputFile).getFileItem()).getName().split("\\.");
        Path storagePath= Paths.get(uploadPath);
        FileSystemUtil.writeFile(storagePath,inputFile.getInputStream());
        jNode = objectMapper.readTree("{\"type\":\"" + "success" + "\",\"fileStorePath\":\"" + pathString + "\"}");
    } catch (Exception exApi) {
        LOGGER.error("Error uploading Party attached Image "+ exApi);
    }
    return jNode;
}
```

This API works fine when used via Postman. The Postman call:

> [image]

But when calling through angular it throws Exception:

**Angular service:**

```
function uploadImage(formData,partyRefId){
        console.log(utilService);
        if (utilService) {
            return utilService.request({
                method: "POST",
                resource: "/images/" + partyRefId,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},
                processData: false,
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                cache: false,
                data: formData
            })
                .then(function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        return getResultDataFromResponse(data);
                    }
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log('error invoking document upload service', error);
                });
        }
    }
```

**Angular Controller:**

```
$ctrl.uploadDocument = function () {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("file", k.documentfile.lfFile);
                var fileName = "PARTY01" + k.documentReference;
                fbeOnboardingWizardService.uploadImage(formData,fileName)
                    .then(function (data) {
                    if(data.type == "success")
                       console.log(data.fileStorePath);
                   },function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                   });
};
```

**Error in Jboss:**

```
02:06:25,442 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) Handler execution resulted in exception: Content type 'null' not supported
```

If I update the **Content-Type** to **"multipart/form-data"** in angular service

**Error in Jboss:**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but wouldn't hurt to try: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/1505#issuecomment-153974345 Is this related to your problem?

Comment: No this doesn't relate to my issue.. But thanks for the reply..

Comment: When we handle file uploads we normally just annotate it like any other form data. Have you tried changing the service to use @RequestParam(name = "file") MultipartFile inputFile?